# Algorithm for finding primitive roots from number theory

Tags: numbers, modular-arithmetic

i would like to implement  program for finding primitive number, for given  prime number, for this one, i wrote following three program

```
function primitive_roots=primitive_root(p)
    if ~isprime(p) 
        error(' p must be  prime number '); 
    end
    primitive_roots=[];
    n=phi(p);
    k=p-1;
    for ii=2:n
        if power_mod(ii,k,p)==1
            primitive_roots=[primitive_roots,ii];
        end
    end

end
```

there is also power_mod function

```
function modresult=power_mod(a,b,c)
%  this program will calculate  a^b mod c
i=0;
result=1;
while i<b
    result=mod(result*a,c);
    i=i+1;
end
modresult=result;


end
```

and euler totient  function

```
 function  phin=phi(n)
    % this function will calculates how many coprime number exist for  given n, coprime number must be
    %less then n

    if isprime(n)  % if number is  prime
        phin=(n-1);
    end
    factors=unique(factor(n));% will printt unique prime divisors of given n
    k=1; % counter
    for ii=1:length(factors)
        k=k*(1-1/factors(ii));
    end
    phin=k*n;



    end
```

but first programs give me incorrect result, for instance

```
>> primitive_roots=primitive_root(19)

primitive_roots =

  Columns 1 through 14

     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15

  Columns 15 through 17

    16    17    18

>>
```

while wolfram alhpa gives me different result

```
https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ef51422db7db201ebc03c8800f41ba99
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

i have solved  this program, for this one i introduced additional function which will calculate all  possible powers and then i am checking for smallest ones

```
function all_powers=powers_list(a,p)
all_powers=[];
for ii=1:p-1
    if power_mod(a,ii,p)==1  %  finding all powers 
        all_powers=[all_powers,ii];
    end
end



end

    function primitive_roots=primitive_root(p)
    if ~isprime(p) 
        error(' p must be  prime number '); 
    end
    primitive_roots=[];
    n=phi(p);
    k=p-1;
    for ii=2:p-1
        if power_mod(ii,k,p)==1
            all_powers=powers_list(ii,p);
            if (min(all_powers)==(p-1))
            primitive_roots=[primitive_roots,ii];
        end
    end

end

>> primitive_roots=primitive_root(5)

primitive_roots =

     2     3

>> primitive_roots=primitive_root(7)

primitive_roots =

     3     5

>> primitive_roots=primitive_root(19)

primitive_roots =

     2     3    10    13    14    15

>> primitive_roots=primitive_root(23)

primitive_roots =

     5     7    10    11    14    15    17    19    20    21

>>
```